# between two columns how to count data in sql? look my query please

Tags: mysql, sql, database

there are two tables, table A and B

tableA

| id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |
| 2 | Katy |

tableB

| t_id | id | date | foods |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2021-06-13 | burger |
| 2 | 1 | 2021-06-14 | fish |
| 3 | 1 | 2021-06-15 | bread |

this table linked with a foreign key.

I want between 2021-06-13 and 2021-06-15 days how many 'foods' john eats?

```
select Name, count(*) as foods 
  from tableA 
  join tableB 
    on tableA.id = tableB.id 
 group 
    by tableB.foods 
 where between date 2021-06-13 and 2021-06-15;
```

Comment: And 2021 minus 6 minus 15 equals 2000

Comment: How are these tables related? Does `t_id` from the second table related to the first one, or `id`?

Answer (score 1):

Since you want the count per person, you need to group by the person, not the food.  And your between syntax is wrong.

```
select Name, count(*) as foods 
  from tableA 
  join tableB 
    on tableA.id = tableB.id 
 where tableB.date between '2021-06-13' and '2021-06-15'
 group 
    by tableA.id;
```

Comment: It said...you have an error in your SQL syntax, check the manual corresponds to......near where tableB.date between '2021-06-13' and '2021-06-15

Comment: Sorry, where goes before group by

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
select a.Name, count(*) as foods 
from tableA a join
     tableB b
     on a.id = b.id 
where b.date >= '2021-06-13' and 
      b.date < '2021-06-16'
group by a.Name;
```

Notes:

- Date constants need to be enclosed in single quotes.
- `WHERE` is a clause that precedes the `GROUP BY` clause.
- The `GROUP BY` columns and `SELECT` columns need to be consistent.
- I changed the date logic so it works even if the "date" column has a time component.
- If you only want one person then you can add a filter such as `and a.name = 'John'`.
- Putting `GROUP` and `BY` on different lines is weird.  `GROUP BY` is a single syntax element in SQL.